# How do I solve this problem Codepoint 984420 not found in font, aborting?

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, flutter-apk

I was trying to build appbundle or apk and it shows:

```
Codepoint 984420 not found in font, aborting.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 59s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            120.1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I  already tried flutter clean and then flutter build appbundle

Comment: Codepoint 984420 is [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Codespace_and_Code_Points) `U+F0564`... that is Supplementary [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Private_Use_Areas)-A, not something you'd expect in source code (or a generic font) of any kind. I'd guess there is some kind of data corruption / conversion error going on...

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: I have no experience with flutter, and am actually not even quite sure what it is you're attempting to do there. I'm just familiar with Unicode, that's all. ;-) Where did you get the sources you're trying to build here, what have you done with them *exactly* up to this point (the error message)?

Comment: I'm trying to export to a appbundle or apk. I have tried upgrade my sdk flutter and change the version of the packages but the result still the same.